# What is the cost of resizing a map?

Tags: data-structures, hashmap

If we consider dynamic arrays, the cost of pushing element is constant on average despite the resize cost:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis#Dynamic_Array

Can we say the same of a resizing hashmap with the following hypothesis:

- Hash functions takes constant time (returning memory address for instance)
- Hash values come in random order
- Hashmap is implemented with simple separate chaining (array of N linked lists)

I am wondering wether using a fixed size hashmap can bring significant performance benefits on average

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the amortized cost of reallocating and rebuilding the hash map is constant per insertion, as long as you always grow it by some factor when you reallocate.

The reason is pretty much the same as for an ArrayList -- as the HashMap grows, the number of maps into which each element will be (re)inserted is constant.

Comment: I think you are right but still not convinced, number of maps into which each element is reinserted will be small for sure but the reinsertion is more costly than with vector, we need to iterate previous array, go through linked list, and iterate through the target linked list in target array to reinsert.
So it looks to me the reinsertion cost in another map is quadratic so not sure it is constant on average.

Comment: You don't actually have to iterate through the target list, since you know that all the elements from the original map are unique.  I'm not trying to convince you, though. I'm trying to help you figure it out for yourself.  You should write some pseudocode to copy a map into one twice the size.  Given that the size of both maps is proportional to the number of elements in the map, you should get O(N) for that operation.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your data and if your hashing function is spreading values equally. The problem appears when a hashing function returns the same key for a lot of values, then you get a really long `LinkedList` and the lookup time start changing from `O(1)` more and more towards `O(n)`. There is a general rule, saying that `load factor` should be about `0.75`. This means that you should start resizing your `HashMap` after it hits around `75%` capacity in order to keep performance around `O(1)`. For more info look [here](http://javabypatel.blogspot.com/2015/10/what-is-load-factor-and-rehashing-in-hashmap.html).

Comment: ok but where does the number 0.75 comes from? 
Also it does not give the average complexity of insert operation, just that the insert operation triggering resize will be slower.